# Cambio el parámetro date.timezone en el php.ini de xampp y las fechas que se insertan tienen diferencia

Tags: php, xampp, date

He instalado un xampp y establezco el parámetro date.timezone = "America/Havana", con la zona horaria de la PC en **(UTC-0500) Hora del este (EE.UU y Canadá)**, y al hacer un insert en la BD a través de la aplicación me genera una fecha con 6 horas de diferencia, por ejemplo para las 06:20 p.m. de hora real, el registro me aparece en pantalla con hora 12:20. qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Señalar que al persistir un registro en la tabla correspondiente, la fecha del mismo la establezco con `$registro->setFechaAnotacion(new \DateTime('now'));`, así que evidentemente es problema del timezone de PHP. Por qué de esa manera, y no dejar que sea el gestor de base de datos el que inserte el valor del campo?: ni recuerdo, tendría que revisar la documentación del proyecto.

Tengo entendido que el xampp trae por defecto la zona horaria de Europe/Berlin, y es como que no me cambia este parámetro al que le establezco, al revisar contra https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/es/ veo que es la hora que está estableciendo.

Comment: Normalmente mysql guarda las fechas en UTC (GMT o Zulu) . Si estás en UTC-5 y la hora tiene 6 hs de diferencia, fijate si no están en época Day Light Saving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay 3 pasos que tienes que dar para ajustar el default-timezone en XAMPP.

1- En el archivo httpd.conf (\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf), añade la siguiente línea:

```
# Set timezone to Continente/Ciudad UTC+00:00 (Coloca aquí tus datos)
SetEnv TZ America/Havana
```

2- Edita en el archivo php.ini (\xampp\php\php.ini) la línea de date.timezone en la sección [Date]:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "America/Havana"
```

Y también en:

```
[Date]
date.timezone=America/Havana
[MySQL]
```

3- Por último modifica el archivo my.ini (\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini), añade o reemplaza, la siguiente línea:

```
default-time-zone = "American/Havana"
```

Ahora reinicia el servidor y ya debería funcionar.